# Iron Router, set a default controller

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to set a default controller for all routes in **Iron Router**?
I'm aware that I can repeat:

```
this.route('...', {
   controller: MyDefaultController,
   // some other options 
}
```

for each **route** that I'm about to define, but I guess that's not the best possible pattern. Also, the **Iron Router** [documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#route-controllers), suggests that I should be able to do something like

```
RouteController.before(function () { /* ... */ };
```

But it seems that this no longer works in the current version. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible at this moment. However, there is another solution. The `Router.configure` routine can be used to create default hooks that will be used with all route controllers. So in particular we can do something like this:

```
Router.configure({
  before: function () {
    console.log('it is working!');
  },
});
```

which is exactly what I need.